# How to remove the axis lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to remove the axis but the label should be there

Eg:current output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

I am using the following code

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=3,
      ymin=0,ymax=3,xstep=1,ystep=1,
      xtick={0,...,3},
      ytick={0,...,3},
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
              ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Set `axis line style={draw=none}` in the `axis` options. To remove the ticks as well, add `tick style={draw=none}` in addition.

In older versions of `pgfplots` the `draw=none` approach for axis lines will not work, but one can set the opacity to zero instead: `axis line style={draw opacity=0}`, or possibly for x- and y-axis separately, `y axis line style={draw opacity=0}, x axis line style={draw opacity=0}`. (Cf. comments.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
    \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0,xmax=3,
      ymin=0,ymax=3,xstep=1,ystep=1,
      xtick={0,...,3},
      ytick={0,...,3},
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
      axis line style={draw=none},
      tick style={draw=none}
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working also form your image "-" still there how I remove "-" this

Comment: @Kevin Do you mean the ticks (the short lines next to the numbers)? I already said so, add `tick style={draw=none}`. (Answer edited.)

Comment: I tried tick style={draw=none} but axis still there and "-" is removed

Comment: @Kevin You need both, obviously. One affects the axis lines, the other the ticks.

Comment: yes I think "axis line style={draw=none}" is not working for me and "tick style={draw=none}" is working

Comment: @Kevin I don't understand. The code that is in my answer now, does that do what you want?

Comment: separate axis lines,
y axis line style= { draw opacity=0 },
x axis line style={draw opacity=0 },     
now it's is worked

Comment: @Kevin OK, good you worked it out. Don't know why my version wouldn't work.

Comment: `axis line style={draw=none}` requires a decent version of `pgfplots`. The opacity approach is a workaround for older versions.