# Draw a surface using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, plot

I am very new to tikz and I would like to draw the following picture
[image]

I attempted and here what I got

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ]
\addplot3[
  surf,
  shader=interp,
  domain=-1:1,
  domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] 
{exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

here is the picture i got but I am stuck on how to use only one color and place a plane on the top of the surface. 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something - just to get you started.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ]
\addplot3[
  surf,
  colormap/blackwhite,
  shader=interp,
  domain=-1:1,
  domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] 
{exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\addplot3[fill=magenta, opacity=0.5]
coordinates{
(-1,-1,1)
(-1,1,1)
(1,1,1)
(1,-1,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface plot with plane]

Comment: hpekristiansen: is there any way to remove the axes ? I  meant the box around the graph ? I will try to go from here. Thanks !!

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314674/how-to-remove-the-axis-lines